# OpenLayers 4.3.4 - Feature, ol.style.icon rotation - rotate heavy but not good?

Tags: openlayers, icon, rotate

I display a feature-marker with `ol.syle.icon`. But when I put a rotation value, the icon rotate heavy in chaos order?

I thought the rotation value 0-360 is clockwise, is not it?

So e.g. a value of 180 should flip the icon horizontaly, but it does not?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon.html#~Options the rotation value is in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), which means it ranges from 0 to 2*Pi instead of 0 to 360°.

Comment: Just a small extension to explicit [@Mesa](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30752/mesa) answer. Instead of 180° flip [@Bytechanger](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/128180/bytechanger) your feature-marker performed the rotation of 233°, because of 180 Rad ≈ 10313°, and 10313° - 10080° = 233°, where 10080° is 28 times 360°.